# SingleStore (MemSQL) How to flatten array using JSON_TO_ARRAY

Tags: sql, arrays, json, singlestore

I have a table `source`:

| data |
| --- |
| { "results": { "rows": [ { "title": "A", "count": 61 }, { "title": "B", "count": 9 } ] }} |
| { "results": { "rows": [ { "title": "C", "count": 43 } ] }} |

And I want a table `dest`:

| title | count |
| --- | --- |
| A | 61 |
| B | 9 |
| C | 43 |

I found there is [JSON_TO_ARRAY](https://docs.singlestore.com/managed-service/en/reference/sql-reference/json-functions/json_to_array.html) function that might be helpful, but got stuck how to apply it.

How to correctly flatten the json array from the table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three options I came up with, which are essentially the same:

```
INSERT INTO dest 
WITH t AS(
  SELECT table_col AS arrRows FROM source JOIN TABLE(JSON_TO_ARRAY(data::results::rows))
)
SELECT arrRows::$title as title, arrRows::%count as count FROM t;
```

```
INSERT INTO dest
SELECT arrRows::$title as title, arrRows::%count as count FROM 
(SELECT table_col AS arrRows FROM source JOIN TABLE(JSON_TO_ARRAY(data::results::rows)));
```

```
INSERT INTO dest
SELECT t.table_col::$title as title, t.table_col::%count as count
FROM source JOIN TABLE(json_to_array(data::results::rows)) t;
```

Answer (score 1):

I have the following that works on your example but it might help you with the syntax.

In this query I created a table called json_tab with a column called jsondata.

```
    With t as (
select table_col AS title FROM json_tab join TABLE(JSON_TO_ARRAY(jsondata::results::rows)))
SELECT t.title::$title title,t.title::$count count FROM t
```

I took example from the code snippet to work with Nested Arrays in a JSON Column

https://github.com/singlestore-labs/singlestoredb-samples/blob/main/JSON/Analyzing_nested_arrays.sql

Comment: useful link, upvoted your answer

Answer (score 0):

It gives the exact output which you requested.

```
with t(rows_) as (
 SELECT a.*
 FROM TABLE(['{"results": { "rows": [ { "title": "A", "count": 61 }, { "title": "B", "count": 9 } ] }}','{ "results": { "rows": [ { "title": "C", "count": 43 } ] }}']) a
    ),t1 as (
    select table_col AS tname
    from t 
    JOIN TABLE(JSON_TO_ARRAY(t.rows_::results::$rows)) a
    )
    SELECT t1.tname::$title as title ,t1.tname::%count as count from t1
```

Useful Links:

[Singstore TABLE](https://docs.singlestore.com/managed-service/en/reference/sql-reference/data-manipulation-language-dml/table.html)

[Singlestore Using JSON](https://docs.singlestore.com/managed-service/en/create-a-database/using-json.html)

[Singlestore JSON Functions](https://docs.singlestore.com/managed-service/en/reference/sql-reference/json-functions.html)

[Singlestore JSON Operators](https://docs.singlestore.com/managed-service/en/create-a-database/using-json.html#using-the-----and-----operators)